# Dynamic Form Generation with Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, product, webshop

The scenario is pretty simple,  I want to enable adding product attributes in my webhop. So, I have product table which holds product information (price, description...), attribute table which defines all possible product attributes (color, weight, power...), product_attributes table which connects this two and holds actual attribute value (red, 25kg, 51w...).

I would like to enable product form to enable adding/editing this attributes (attribute set is defined in attribute table).

I tried using [collections](https://github.com/umpirsky/Sylius-Sandbox/blob/product-attributes/src/Sylius/Sandbox/Bundle/AssortmentBundle/Form/Type/ProductType.php#L42), but that allowed me to only edit existing product attributes, not to add new.

I also experimented with event subscribers, but everything I add does not fit in my Product entity, it is just not that flexible to accept anything, it asks for attributes.

Is there any good way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want with [Embedding Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html), and using some jQuery magic to make it pretty.

It's explained in detail in the guide. With collections you need to use :

```
'allow_add' => true, 'by_reference' => false,
```

to allow the users to add new attributes.

Comment: Thanks, I know, but I would like to enable product form to enable adding/editing this attributes (attribute set is defined in attribute table). So I want input field for each attribute from attribute table. Which means text input with label Color, then text input with label Weight...and same for each entry from attribute table. No JavaScript. Thanks again.